# How to use ForcedSubject in CASL

Tags: typescript, casl

I am following CASL's cookbook on implementing authorization for roles with predfined permissions ([see here](https://casl.js.org/v5/en/cookbook/roles-with-static-permissions)) and I am blocked when I try to check abilities for a user.

I do not understand how `ForcedSubject` is meant to be used. I do not which to use classes or interfaces to define my subjects so I therefore rely on strings. However, all my subjects do contain a `id` property and I want the ability to check permissions with conditionals on that ID. Bellow is a simplified version of what I implemented.

```js
import { Ability, AbilityClass, ForcedSubject } from '@casl/ability';

type OrgActions =
  | 'manage'
  | 'invite-user';

type SubjectWithId = { id: string };
type MyAbilities =
  | ['manage', 'all']
  | [OrgActions, 'organization' | ForcedSubject<SubjectWithId>];

export type MyAbility = Ability<MyAbilities>;
export const MyAbility = Ability as AbilityClass<MyAbility>;


const builder = new AbilityBuilder(PlatformAbility)
builder.can('invite-user', 'organization', { id: 'abcd' })

const ability = builder.build()
ability.can('invite-user', 'organization') // No problem here
ability.can('invite-user', subject('organization', { id: 'abcd' }) // Typing Error!
```

Here is the typing error I get.

```
Argument of type '["invite-user", { id: string; } & ForcedSubject<"organization">]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[action: "manage", subject: "all", field?: string | undefined] | [action: OrgActions, subject: "organization" | ForcedSubject<SubjectWithId>, field?: string | undefined]'.
  Type '["invite-user", { id: string; } & ForcedSubject<"organization">]' is not assignable to type '[action: OrgActions, subject: "organization" | ForcedSubject<SubjectWithId>, field?: string | undefined]'.
    Type at position 1 in source is not compatible with type at position 1 in target.
      Type '{ id: string; } & ForcedSubject<"organization">' is not assignable to type '"organization" | ForcedSubject<SubjectWithId>'.
        Type '{ id: string; } & ForcedSubject<"organization">' is not assignable to type 'ForcedSubject<SubjectWithId>'.
          Types of property '__caslSubjectType__' are incompatible.
            Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'SubjectWithId'.ts(2345)
```

I do not understand how the `ForceSubject` type is supposed to be used if not with the `subject` helper like I did.

Answer (score 0):

The error you encountered is due to the type you passed to `ForcedSubject`.

You need to provide the type your ability expects and `subject` is supposed to force your object into. In your example, you want CASL to recognise plain objects being forced into an `'organization'` subject, so you need to pass `'organization'` to `ForcedSubject`. Thus, your type `MyAbilities` should look like this:

```
type MyAbilities =
  | ['manage', 'all']
  | [OrgActions, 'organization' | ForcedSubject<'organization'>]
```

Note that this allows you to have only some subject types be forceable, providing greater type-safety for any subject type that might use classes instead of plain objects.